# access custom post type for styling and querys

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have successfully created a new post type called `movies`, but in `wordpress` you access/style your posts inside `index.php`, `page.php` but how do I access the new post type movies as I have tried with `movies.php`. it does work in `single-movies.php`. do I just add some conditional logic to `index.php` so that it knows its movies rather than just posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a archive-movies.php by simply duplicating your current archive.php file.

Comment: Thanks m8 .. so easy when you know how.